# Does this scatterplot indicate homoscedasticity?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, scatterplot

Can anyone perhaps confirm if it is true that this scatterplot indicates that my data is homoscedastic?

[image]

Since there are quite some more datapoints on the upper side, I was a bit hesitating.
Thanks a lot!